# Design a firewall to block all traffic from 10.0.0.0/24 except port 23 and 80 of TCP

Tags: linux

I know the approach with ipfwadm but need the same using iptables command.
Please help its urgent

Comment: This is not a script writing service. If you show what you have done, then we can help. But we don't write stuff for you.

Comment: Consider also `nftables`, it is the replacement no `iptables` and is atomic, and easier to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp -p tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j DROP
```

Make changes persistent:

```
$ sudo service iptables save
$ sudo service iptables restart
```

Or you could edit the config file `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` and add the lines underneath the `COMMIT` line:

```
-A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp -p tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j DROP
```

And restart the service:

```
$ sudo service iptables restart
```

Comment: Can it be more compact and precise?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I added an alternate method that involves using the config file, and that detracts from the command string a bit

Comment: You are correct, updated!

Comment: Ok thanks it worked!